# How to hide the name input field before uploading file

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide the input for file name. I tried it in CSS but it does not work.  After browsing file i want to show the input file name. Is it possible in CSS?

```css
.input-group-btn{
  width:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();">Choose File</span>
    <input name="uploaded_file" onchange="$(this).parent().parent().find('.form-control').html($(this).val().split(/[\\|/]/).pop());" style="display: none;" type="file">
  </span>
  <span class="form-control"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont understand what you want to hide.  Is it `<span class="form-control">` where the name is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code of Kamil is right, this line that you see is generated by the iframe that constains the code but is just for stackover page,  i just added a `<br/>` and now looks ok.

```css
.input-group-btn{
  width:10px;
}
.yourHiddenClassName:empty{
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<br/><br/><div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();">Choose File</span>
    <input name="uploaded_file" onchange="$(this).parent().parent().find('.form-control').html($(this).val().split(/[\\|/]/).pop());" style="display: none;" type="file">
  </span>
  <span class="form-control yourHiddenClassName"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understood correctly , but here is modified code snippet:

```css
.input-group-btn{
  width:10px;
}
.yourHiddenClassName:empty{
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();">Choose File</span>
    <input name="uploaded_file" onchange="$(this).parent().parent().find('.form-control').html($(this).val().split(/[\\|/]/).pop());" style="display: none;" type="file">
  </span>
  <span class="form-control yourHiddenClassName"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly that is what I want. But in your example I can still see the line above

Comment: Line above was added by external stackoverflow css, copy this code to your project - top border will disappear. Please mark as answer if it works fine :)